# How to apply in the server changes made in the client, like deleting or modifying entities

Tags: asp.net, json, entity-framework, knockout.js

I don't know how to remove elements from related table in EF.

Test Json data:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Number": "000100029304",
    "Title": "Test Title",
    "Status": "Ready",
    "StatusDate": null,
    "Author": null,
    "UpdatedDate": "2012-12-12T12:12:12",
    "Comments": "test comment",


    "Links": [
      {
          "$id": "4",
          "DocumentId": 1234,
          "Name": "Some file1.xls",
          "Path": "\\\\mycomp\\folder\\Some file1.xls",
          "Type": 0,
          "Document": {
              "$ref": "1"
          },
          "ID": 200
      },
      {
          "$id": "5",
          "DocumentId": 1234,
          "Name": "Some file2.xls",
          "Path": "\\\\mycomp\\folder\\Some file2.xls",
          "Type": 0,
          "Document": {
              "$ref": "1"
          },
          "ID": 201
      },
    ],
    "ID": 1234
}
```

For example the user gets a `Model` from the server and makes some changes in its entities - like update, adde or remove links - by using knockout js, and sends the changes back to the server.

On the server side the received data is deserialized into `Model` and tries to apply the changes.

I know how to insert new links:

```
if (mylink.ID == 0) {context.Entry(mylink).State = EntityState.Added;}
else {context.Entry(mylink).State = EntityState.Modified;}
```

But I can find no way to delete links that were deleted in the client. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right technique: attach to the `DbContext` and change the entity state.

Your only problem is that you're not tracking the deleted entities and sending them back to the server. There are multiple options to delete (or update) the changed entities in the server:

1. Add an observable to your entities (links), for example `state: ko.observable()` which can be `added`, `unchanged`, `modified`, or `deleted`. When deleting the entities, instead of removing them from the array, mark them as `deleted`. It's easy to hide the entities using this property with knockout, for example with `data-bind="visible: state()!='deleted'` (much better if you use a computed to do this check), or filtering the array of links with a computed or using something like [ko projections](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/12/03/knockout-projections-a-plugin-for-efficient-observable-array-transformations/) to filter the array.
2. Send the list of links back to the server, compare them with the ones in the database, and apply the corresponding changes, by deleting or changing them, depending on the result of the comparison.
3. Similar to the previous one: send the list of links to the server and simply delete all the links in the server and save the received ones.
4. If the entities in the client side are like the ones in the EF `DbContext` you can use the extremely powerful [Breeze.js](http://www.getbreezenow.com/) that allows you to automatically track changes in the client side, and send them back to the server. In fact, you can use it nearly as a client side EF, and it gets on very well with knockout.

*NOTE: The main problem that doesn't allow you to find a solution is that you want to use the `Model` as is for sending the data from and to the server. You must use something different. For example, in the 1st solution you need to add the `state` property also on the server size, to deserialize and use it. You can use a whole new class, or simply add the property to your entities but ignore it with an EF attribute, as you don't want to save it in the DB. On the last solution everything happens behind the scenes, so you don't need to do it by hand.*